# Trouble in calculating the field while creating view in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables `q1data` and `q1lookup` in postgres database. `q1data` contains 3 columns (`postid`, `reasonid`, `other`) and `q1lookup` contains 2 columns (`reasonid`, `reason`).

I am trying to create a view which will include 4 columns (`reasonid`, `reason`, `count`, `percentage`). `count` is the count of each `reason` and `percentage` should be each `count` divided by total of `count(*) from q1data` (i.e. total rows if `reasonid`).

But it gives an error and says syntax error near `count(*)`. The following is the code I am using. Please help.

```
select 
     cwfis_web.q1data.reasonid AS reasonid,
     cwfis_web.q1lookup.reason AS reason,
     count(cwfis_web.q1data.reasonid) AS count,
     round(
        (
            (
                count(cwfis_web.q1data.reasonid) 
                / 
                (select count(0) AS count(*) from cwfis_web.q1data)
            ) * 100
        )
     ,0) AS percentage 
from 
     cwfis_web.q1data 
join 
     cwfis_web.q1lookup 
     ON cwfis_web.q1data.reasonid = cwfis_web.q1lookup.reasonid 
group by 
     cwfis_web.q1data.reasonid;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you have a completely invalid piece of syntax there: `count(0) AS count(*)`. Replacing that with a plain `count(*)`, and adding the missing `Group By` entry for `reason`, gives this:

```
select 
     cwfis_web.q1data.reasonid AS reasonid,
     cwfis_web.q1lookup.reason AS reason,
     count(cwfis_web.q1data.reasonid) AS count,
     round(
        (
            (
                count(cwfis_web.q1data.reasonid) 
                / 
                (select count(*) from cwfis_web.q1data)
            ) * 100
        )
     ,0) AS percentage 
from 
     cwfis_web.q1data 
join 
     cwfis_web.q1lookup 
     ON cwfis_web.q1data.reasonid = cwfis_web.q1lookup.reasonid 
group by 
     cwfis_web.q1data.reasonid,
     cwfis_web.q1lookup.reason;
```

However, [as this live demo shows](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/696bf/2) this doesn't give the right value for `percentage`, because `count(cwfis_web.q1data.reasonid)` and `(select count(*) from cwfis_web.q1data)` are both of type `integer`, so integer division is performed, and the result truncated to `0`.

If you cast these to `numeric` (the expected argument type of [the 2-parameter `round()` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html), you get this:

```
select 
     cwfis_web.q1data.reasonid AS reasonid,
     cwfis_web.q1lookup.reason AS reason,
     count(cwfis_web.q1data.reasonid) AS count,
     round(
        (
            (
                count(cwfis_web.q1data.reasonid)::numeric
                / 
                (select count(*) from cwfis_web.q1data)::numeric
            ) * 100
        )
     ,0) AS percentage 
from 
     cwfis_web.q1data 
join 
     cwfis_web.q1lookup 
     ON cwfis_web.q1data.reasonid = cwfis_web.q1lookup.reasonid 
group by 
     cwfis_web.q1data.reasonid,
     cwfis_web.q1lookup.reason;
```

Which as [this live demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/696bf/3) shows gives something more like you were hoping for. (Alternatively, you can cast to `float`, and lose the `,0` argument to `round()`, [as in this demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/696bf/1).)

Comment: Glad to be of help. If this answer solved your problem, please tick it as "Accepted" so that others can see that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your subquery from

```
select count(0) AS count(*) from cwfis_web.q1data
```

to

```
select count(0) from cwfis_web.q1data
```

Also you need to add `cwfis_web.q1lookup.reason` to `group by`.